# How to send upstream messages with FCM from android client?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

We were using `GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context).send(context.getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId) + "@gcm.googleapis.com", mId, mBundle);` to send upstream messages, but since I was trying to migrate new `fcm` concept, I need to change that too, but could not find any documentation yet.

My best guess is to use :

```
RemoteMessage message = new RemoteMessage.Builder(<?>).setMessageId(mId).setData ...
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

but then what is it the Builder takes as a parameter? Yet again, could not find api...

So simply as title states, how to send upstream messages using new `fcm` concept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, my answer comes fast. Keeping question and answer for future reference. I have found the answer on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream#sample-send

thanks to google's smart exclusion to search results `In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 2 already displayed.
If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.`

new API would be like:

```
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
  .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
  .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
  .addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
  .build());
```

Comment: What is a SENDER_ID?

Comment: @SergioLucas Check this one:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials

Comment: @guness, how to send to a particular user using the refreshToken?

Comment: Also, the link that you have given in the answer is not working.

Comment: @AbAppletic something random. it will be send back to you to.

Comment: here how can i send to particular channel?

Comment: @Suchith this is another question.

Comment: hi @guness thanks. may i know how to send upstream message to particular user by device token? may question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038784/how-to-send-push-notification-programmatically-on-specific-firebase-fcm-register

Comment: I need to send a message on topic can I do that through Android Client?

Comment: @Avi AFAIK, you need to send your message to your server, then your server can deliver the message.

Comment: As I know we can send a RemoteMessage using FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send() method, so what it will do?

Comment: @avi it pushes your message to server. your server should use XMPP FCM Connection Server Protocol. check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choose

Answer (score 1):

Well you can send your message directly to android devices from android application, here is the simple implementation I have done and it works great for me.

1. compile android volley library

   ```
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
   ```
2. Just copy paste this simple function ;) and your life will become smooth just like knife in butter. :D

   ```
   public static void sendPushToSingleInstance(final Context activity, final HashMap dataValue /*your data from the activity*/, final String instanceIdToken /*firebase instance token you will find in documentation that how to get this*/ ) {


   final String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
   StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   Toast.makeText(activity, "Bingo Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   Toast.makeText(activity, "Oops error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }) {

       @Override
       public byte[] getBody() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
           Map<String,String> rawParameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();
           rawParameters.put("data", new JSONObject(dataValue).toString());
           rawParameters.put("to", instanceIdToken);
           return new JSONObject(rawParameters).toString().getBytes();
       };

       public String getBodyContentType()
       {
           return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       }
       @Override
       public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
           HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
           headers.put("Authorization", "key="+YOUR_LEGACY_SERVER_KEY_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE);
           return headers;
       }

   };

   Volley.newRequestQueue(activity).add(myReq);
   }
   ```

**Note**
If you want to send message to topics so you can change parameter **instanceIdToken** to something like **/topics/topicName**. 
For **groups** implementation is the same but you just need to take care of parameters. [checkout Firebase documentation and you can pass those parameters.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)
***let me know if you face any issue.***

Comment: so you want to expose `YOUR_LEGACY_SERVER_KEY_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE` which should be kind of secret?

Comment: Yes that is true it should be a secret. But point is that if someone can not do server side code then this solution can be used. I have seen people wants some kind of testing code for prototype of projects.

Comment: Am getting Error "Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" when I try up your snippet. What can I do?

Comment: @Neri i received the same error message as well, any solutions ?

Comment: I have moved on , this implementation may have changed now. :) You shall apply server side script for a better solution . @ACAkgul