# Firebase upstream messages

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending upstream message most of the times the message does not get to my server, and even when the message received to the server the `onMessageSent(String msgId)` function isn't called (the `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage fcmMessage)` work very well).

Why the function isn't called and why do I need to send 10 upstream messages to get response from the firebase cloud messaging to my server?

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String sendTo = SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com";
            RemoteMessage.Builder data = new RemoteMessage.Builder(sendTo);
            data.addData("Hello", "World");

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    String messageID = getRandomString();
                    data.setMessageId(messageID);
                    Logger.d(TAG, "messageID: " + messageID);
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(data.build());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "Error sending upstream message: " + e.getMessage());
                return "Error sending upstream message:" + e.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "send message failed: " + result);
            }
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem!!!
The problem was on the server side.
Every time I send a message to the app (android), I started a new connection to the gcm server, when maintaining a continuous connection it worked great.
For the problem with the onMessageSent not called it was because, before you send the message you need to set time to live (setTtl(Time_in_seconds)) for the message.

```
    RemoteMessage.Builder data = new RemoteMessage.Builder(mSendTo);

    data.setMessageId(messageID);
    data.setTtl(120);


    data.addData("Hello", "World");

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(data.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

buttonUpstreamEcho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Echo Upstream message logic");
            String message = editTextEcho.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message + ", recipient: " + token);
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(FCM_PROJECT_SENDER_ID + FCM_SERVER_CONNECTION)
                    .setMessageId(Integer.toString(RANDOM.nextInt()))
                    .addData("message", message)
                    .addData("action", BACKEND_ACTION_ECHO)
                    .build());
            // To send a message to other device through the XMPP Server, you should add the
            // receiverId and change the action name to BACKEND_ACTION_MESSAGE in the data
        }
    });
```

This is a sample Android project to showcase the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to manage upstream and downstream messages.

https://github.com/carlosCharz/FCMTest

This is the video in youtube that explains what it does.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEzOKSoAMG0

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the builder pattern - it is always best to chain your calls to the setter methods. So my suggestion, and based on some working examples such as [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337432/how-to-send-upstream-messages-with-fcm-from-android-client?rq=1), would be to change your code into something like this (note that I got rid of the for-loop - you can put it back if you need it, I don't see why - perhaps you were testing out?:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String sendTo = SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com";
             String messageID = getRandomString();            
            try {
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(sendTo)
                   .setMessageId(messageID)
                   .addData("my_message", "Hello, World")
                   .build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "Error sending upstream message: " + e.getMessage());
                return "Error sending upstream message:" + e.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Logger.e(TAG, "send message failed: " + result);
            }
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

I hope this helps - try it out and let me know if it works or what errors you are getting.

Comment: I get messages from firebase-cloud-messaging, but i have to send more then one message to get it (that is why the for-loop).

Comment: And to chain the calls to the setter methods did not helped.