# How to send push notification programmatically on specific firebase FCM registered token in Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, chat

I want to know that is there any way to send push notification programmatically on particular FCM registered token (Device token)? i had implemented group chat but stuck in one-one chat.

I don't want to use any web-service or any back-end at all, because i am using Firebase database and storage as a Back-end in my application.

i want to send upstream message to particular device token.

Any idea's how to do that ? thanks.

Comment: you can send msg using java code by FCM endpoint url.

Comment: why don't you try with the help of Firebase dashboard ?

Comment: thank you @DivyeshPatel can you provide any reference link?

Comment: yes i know @TGMCians that but don't want to use every-time so that i want  implement in app-app

Comment: i wanna send upstream msg to particular user from app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42548586/6756514

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase to provide backend functionality without having to manage your own backend servers.

Comment: Hello @MehulGajjar AFAIK device to device Push messages are not available. However you can use Firebase live database for that purpose.